# In iOS, does a segue instantiate the new-to-be-used view controller? Or is it already instantiated?

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

So for instance, let's say I have a regular subclass of UIViewController and I have connected a control object contained within this controller's view to a segue action that will let another view controller's view come into view...

Simple enough.

When I call the method called prepare(for:sender:) on the regular subclassed UIViewController, at this point, I'm concerned with the new to be used view controller whose view will pop on the screen.. Is this new view controller already instantiated somewhere?

I believe the answer is yes because inside the prepare(for:sender:) function, I set a reference for segue.destination (which is the destination view controller) and when I print that reference, it seems to be a place in memory already which tells me that the new view controller is already instantiated.

Can anyone confirm/deny that this new view controller (created from the storyboard) already has been instantiated, or put this in simpler terms?

Thanks

Comment: This is easily knowable. Override the view controller's init methods and log when and how new instances are created.

Comment: In my testing, a new instance is created each and every time when segueing to a details view controller in a split view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's documentation says,

> When the storyboard runtime detects a custom segue, it creates a new instance of your class, configures it with the view controller objects, asks the view controller source to prepare for the segue, and then performs the segue.

( https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboardsegue )

So the destination UIViewController is instantiated by the segue just before sending `prepareForSegue` to the source UIViewController.

So to answer your questions directly, it is "yes" to both questions:

> In iOS, does a segue instantiate the new-to-be-used view controller?

Yes, the segue does instantiate the destination view controller.

> Or is it already instantiated?

Yes, by the time your `prepareForSegue` is called, it is already instantiated - immediately beforehand.

**UPDATE**:  As @Jeffery_Thomas commented, this is trivially easy to demonstrate by adding an `NSLog()` line to your destination view controller's `init`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone confirm/deny that this new view controller (created from the storyboard) already has been instantiated,

Yes. That is what it *means* to trigger a segue. A triggered segue's *job* is to instantiate the destination view controller, and `prepare` exists so that you can configure *that instance*.